# ASP.NET Core Project - Publish doesn't show the "Database Migrations" option

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

My project used to work perfectly for .NET Core 1.0, but moving to 1.1 is causing me days of headache!!  I've been using **Microsoft Azure** for publishing and hadn't had too many problems.

I think I'm down to just the database migrations.  I've been using migrations for quite a while now, but when I publish, I don't get the option to '**Apply this migration on publish**'.

I have a second project that's working just fine.  When I open up the publishing screen, an icon spins saying '**Discovering Data Contexts...**' and then changes to '**Entity Framework Migrations**'.

But for the life of me, I can't get it to work with my main project!!

**What could be preventing the 'Entity Framework Migrations' from appearing while publishing?**

I've done **add-migration Init** and **update-database** and those work perfectly locally, but not when trying to publish

My ApplicationDbContext.cs is just a default, and works with the other project.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options){
    }
```

dotnet --info

```
 .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)
```

And when I run locally, I can delete the SQL Database and Migration puts it back when I start.  So I know Migration is working properly.  I just can't get the option to show up during publish.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit this issue, the **'Discovering Data Contexts...'** spinner ran for a bit and then I didn't get the **'Entity Framework Migrations'** option at all.

What fixed it for me was recreating the publish profile as follows:

From the Publish screen press the Create new profile link:
[image: Publish to Azure screen]

And then change to the Select Existing option:

[image: Publish Select Existing]

Then pick your existing App Service

[image]

Once I did that, the **'Entity Framework Migrations'** section showed up as expected in the Publish tool's Settings.

For info, recreating the publishing file doesn't seem to have made any major changes in the .pubmxl file.  The only changes were `resourcegroups` was changed to `resourceGroups` in the `<ResourceId>` setting, and `<PublishFramework />` was changed to `<PublishFramework></PublishFramework>`.  Neither of those seem likely to be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue. Unfortunately I don't have an answer *yet*.

I don't have a specific answer, but I know that it's a known issue for vs2017 RC right now: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2017.md#migrations-not-applied-during-publish

It says to manually apply these migrations, but since I'm using the new project type, I don't have access to the `dotnet ef` command line tools.

If you have the command line tools available for your project (you're still using project.json and such), then I believe there is a `-script` option which allows you to output a script for your migration, which you can then run manually on the server.

I've raised an issue on the efcore github here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7276

Comment: I eventually just had to create a new project, and copy all of my code over to it.  Thanks for the reply and the update!

Comment: No problem.
I got mine working by using the `Script-Migration` tool in the package manager console to generate a sql script of all my migrations with the `-Idempotent` flag, then ran that sql against my server on azure.